# Specifying Font Size/Style in Label Expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser

I want to create a label expression with two lines of text, this should be simple but I'm having a lot of trouble. Basically, I need the top line to be 10 pt font, and the next line to be 8pt font that is italicized.

This is what I have:

```
    def FindLabel ( [LABEL1], [LABEL2] ):
      return "<FNT size = '10'>" + [LABEL1] + "</FNT>" + "\n" + "<FNT size = '8'><ITA>" + [LABEL2] + "</FNT><ITA>"
```

This is interpreting the formatting as a string, so it's just spitting out exactly what I put in.

The piece of code below will work fine, but as soon as I add the new line everything is messed up.

```
    "<FNT size = '10'>" + [LABEL1] + "</FNT>"
```

I would like to do this using Python.

Comment: Although you've been a member here for a while, I note you still haven't taken the new user **[tour]** which states there should be only one question per Question.  Please ask your second question separately.

Comment: @Tom your final italic tag should be `</ITA>` not `<ITA>`.

Answer (score 3):

You fell a victim to the Expression Verification window (activated by clicking the `Verify` button).

The code:

```
def FindLabel ( [CITY_NAME] , [POP1990]  ):
  return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '12'>" + [CITY_NAME] + "</FNT></CLR>" + "\n" + "<CLR blue='255'><FNT size = '10'>" + [POP1990] + "</FNT></CLR>"
```

[image]

The new lines won't be rendered properly there. You have to hit `OK` and then `Apply` and actually see how labels look on the map.

[image]

It is also possible to include other tags such as `<BOL>` and `<ITA>`:

```
def FindLabel ( [CITY_NAME] , [POP1990]  ):
  return "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '12'><ITA>" + [CITY_NAME] + "</ITA></FNT></CLR>" + "\n" + "<CLR blue='255'><FNT size = '10'><BOL>" + [POP1990] + "</BOL></FNT></CLR>"
```

[image]

Comment: That does work, however, the problem still persists. When I add the <BOL> or <ITA>  tags, it still displays the full string of code, on the map and in the verification window.

Comment: Added a sample with ITA and BOL, shouldn't be a problem. Make sure you use the right syntax; easy to miss a character.